# Верстка интернет-магазина

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вот допустим есть такой макет. Я не могу понять что будет делать человек когда ему нужно будет добавлять/удалять товар. Со стороны front-end я должен какой то функционал писать или это все back-end? Как это в жизни происходит?

[image: магазин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователь будет кликать по товарам, выбирать их количество и т.п. Соответственно, прежде чем отправлять запрос серверу, эти все манипуляции нужно как-то обработать на стороне браузера. Т.е. это всё front-end.

Обычно всё происходит так:

По мере того, как пользователь добавляет покупки в корзину, информация о его выборе дописывается в куки.
И когда он завершает выбор и приступает к оформлению товара, информация о всех его выборах вытягивается из куки, и отправляется на сервер.

Ну, либо если это зарегистрированный пользователь, то можно и без куки, сразу по мере добавления товаров в корзину записывать его выборы на сервер.

Но в любом случае должна быть клиентская часть, которая будет обеспечивать всю механику интерфейса и отправлять запросы на сервер.

Answer (score 3):

1. Добавление/удаление товара в интернет магазине - это front-end и
   этот функционал действительно нужно писать
2. Этот функционал служебный и поэтому его обычно реализуют в какой-нибудь панели администратора, где находится смежный/похожий функционал -
   импорт/экспорт всех или по фильтру товарных позиций в 1C, Яндекс.Маркет, csv и т.д.